# use where in doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

I have a table in my database: article
It has the rows: id, title, num

I am trying to make a query in Doctrine 2 to show the article with the max "num" number.

I need help to properly use "where" in my query into articleController
Or if you have some better solution

```
public function articleAction()
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('appBundle:Article');
    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('a.id','a.title','a.num')
            ->where("a.num AS Max(a.num)")
            ->getQuery()
            ;
            $article = $query->getResult();
    return $this->render('appBundle:articles:article.html.twig', array('article'=>$article));
}
```

Comment: That's not valid where clause syntax even if you weren't using QueryBuilder.    Since when can you have WHERE a.num AS Max(a.num)?

What are you trying to do?  WHERE a.num = (SELECT MAX(num) FROM Article)?

Comment: Hi gview, exactly, i would like to show the article with the maximum value of num.  Given num is into integer type.

Comment: this solved my prob : public function art_lastAction()
    {
        // single createQuery
        $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $dql   = ("SELECT a.title, a.id, a.num FROM RiehBundle:Article a ORDER BY a.num DESC");
                
        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
        $query ->setMaxResults(1);
        $art_last = $query->getResult(); 

        return $this->render('RiehBundle:articles:art_last.html.twig', array('art_last'=>$art_last)); 
        
    }

Comment: That is what I was going to suggest, only I would add a LIMIT 1 to your original query.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your help ;-) ... Defining a limit is in fact one the best solutions to implement it

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution

```
public function articleAction() {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('appBundle:Article');
    $article = $repository->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('a.id','a.title','a.num')
            ->orderBy('a.num', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

    return $this->render('appBundle:articles:article.html.twig', array(
                'article'=>$article)
            );
}
```

Comment: Hi dhvarela, this example also help me a lot because i needed to how to implement it by using "createQueryBuilder" instead of createQuery. Thank you a lot.

Comment: So the "getOneOrNullResult()" method is used to limit the result ?!! ok ...

Comment: Yes, you can see more options [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats)